# Filling up a table in R

Tags: r, vector

I've got 2 vectors:

```
c1 <- c(1,2,0,1,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,0)
c2 <- c(1,2,0,5,0,2,1)

> table(c1)   
c1   
0 1 2 3 4 5 6   
2 3 2 2 1 1 1   
> table(c2)  
c2  
0 1 2 5   
2 2 2 1
```

Now I want `c2` to have the following form:

```
> table(c2)  
c2  
0 1 2 3 4 5 6   
2 2 2 0 0 1 0
```

How can I get out of these tables the vectors (2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1) and (2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0)?

Comment: See also [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773435/how-can-you-force-inclusion-of-a-level-in-a-table-in-r/19773510#19773510) or [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617061/including-absent-values-in-table-results-in-r/1617150#1617150).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So R doesn't know that there are missing values.  The easiest way to convince it of this is to specify that the `levels` of the `factor` include missing elements.

For example

```
> table(factor(c2, levels=0:6))

0 1 2 3 4 5 6
2 2 2 0 0 1 0
```

For the second part of this question, usually the table itself is adequate for most purposes.

```
> a <- table(factor(c2, levels=0:6))
> a[1] + 1
0
3
```

if you ignore the "0" header, then you can do almost any vector manipulation.  But if you want to remove the headers completely, you can convert to a raw numeric array

```
> as.numeric(a)
[1] 2 2 2 0 0 1 0
```

Comment: I think the OP wanted levels corresponding to `c1` rather than setting them manually

Answer (score 2):

Use `factor` and pass unique values of `c1` to `levels` of `c2` in order to set empty entries corresponding to `c1` values

```
table(factor(c2, levels = sort(unique(c1))))
# 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
# 2 2 2 0 0 1 0
```

Or use `union` (as mentioned in @Svens deleted answer)

```
table(factor(c2, levels = sort(union(c1, c2))))
# 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
# 2 2 2 0 0 1 0
```

In order to get the actual values use `as.numeric`

```
as.numeric(table(factor(c2, levels = sort(unique(c1)))))
## [1] 2 2 2 0 0 1 0
```