Contingency table for rater data without values for one rater
I'm still learning R and I hit on a (possibly trivial???) problem quite early on.
I have data from several sets of 2 raters assigning 3 ratings (Good, Acceptable, Unacceptable) to services. I would like to compute Kappa agreement for all the sets of 2 raters. I'm using the irr library. Works fine except for some pairs, one rater didn't assign the score "Unacceptable" at all. So the table I get is not square and the Kappa command returns an error.
I'm subsetting (subset()) the dataset to get the two columns with scores and create a table from them with the table() command. I get this table for instance:




Good
Acceptable
Unacceptable




Good
103
0
7


Acceptable
50
252
12



I'd need to add a row with zeros for the rater who didn't assign Unacceptable like so:




Good
Acceptable
Unacceptable




Good
103
0
7


Acceptable
50
252
12


Unacceptable
0
0
0



I tried binding a vector c(0,0,0) directly (didn't work) as well as first defining the ratings:
categories <- c("Good", "Acceptable", "Unacceptable")
and then doing dimnames(ratings) <- list(Rater1 = categories, Rater2 = categories)
This doesn't work either.
I don't seem to find a way to do it... Could I please ask for help? Thank you.

Found the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773435/how-can-you-force-inclusion-of-a-level-in-a-table-in-r
Thank you!
